# Spring boot, Update/override application.properties value programatically/dynamically (JAVA)

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, jwt, caffeine-cache

I am using Spring boot. Application uses JWT token(another micro service) for authentication. I have to implement caching of JWT token. I am using Caffeine Cache.

**Problem:**
Now the problem is this token expiry time is always dynamic and i have to match token expiry time with Cache expiry time. i.e.

Cache expiry time <= Token expiry time

**Question:** Is there any way to achieve this using Spring Cache?

Can we set value of below property dynamically, depends on JWT token expiry time?

```
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=expireAfterWrite=600s
```

Comment: You would like to set this property based on other property from your properties file or change it dynamically during runtime for each JWT that you receive? I am not sure if latter is possbile.

Comment: Caffeine has support for per-entry custom expiration or dynamically changing a fixed duration period. These fall outside of Spring Cache which targets the simplest use-cases. My understanding is that in advanced cases they recommend using the native APIs directly.

Comment: @MichałKrzywański Yes, I actually want the latter one. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.setProperty()` to change the value of environment variable from code.